# Parsing CSV file and creating a key value pair

Tags: csv, groovy

I am currently new and dabbling with groovy. I made a simple function called `parseCsvFile`. This function reads from a CSV file. However, when I try to `println` I don see the values but instead `import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader`. My ultimate goal is to read the csv file and create a key value pair based in the data. How could I best accomplish that?

Function for parsing:

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVParser

def parseCsvFile(String csvFilePath){
    if (fileExists(csvFilePath)) {
        new File(csvFilePath).withReader { reader ->
            CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader)
            csvReader.each { fields ->
                println fields
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw error
    }        

    //return a key value array
}
```

Example of csv:

```
GAME_ID,GAME_NAME,OLD_OWNER_NAME,NEW_OWNER_NAME,ORG_NAME
20001,str.git,Gemini,Kitoshi,Blue-DiamondGames
30001,str.git,Kashi,Sensu,FlyingMonkey
```

Comment: MaryCoding, please check the solution to see if that is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using groovy, you could simple use [groovycsv](https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv) and achieve the same with so simple as shown below:

**Example - csv as String**

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.1')
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv

def csv = """GAME_ID,GAME_NAME,OLD_OWNER_NAME,NEW_OWNER_NAME,ORG_NAME
20001,str.git,Gemini,Kitoshi,Blue-DiamondGames
30001,str.git,Kashi,Sensu,FlyingMonkey"""

def data = parseCsv(csv)
for(line in data) {
    println "$line.GAME_ID $line.GAME_NAME"
}
```

You can also use data from file. Just put the above data in csv file and provide input to `FileReader` and pass it to `parseCsv` method as shown below:

**Example - csv as File**

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.1')
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv
//Change the filepath as per your environment
def data = parseCsv(new FileReader('/tmp/game.csv'))
for(line in data) {
    println "$line.GAME_ID $line.GAME_NAME"
}
```

Note: You should be able to use column name to refer the data if you notice above `println` statement

Comment: Could you do this with the import from `au.com.bytecode.opencsv.`?  For some reason the environment I am in does not resolve `com.xlson.groovycsv.`

Comment: How are you running the above script? You can go to the provided link in the answer and download the library and mentioned dependencies. Then add them to classpath. You are good to go, I guess. `groovycsv` uses `opencsv` only behind the scenes which you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should probably not use ancient versions of a library. In the version you are using (<= 2.3), the `CSVReader` is not an instance of `Iterable`, so the `each` method called is the one from `Object` which just iterates over the object itself. If you use a more recent version (>= 2.4) of the same library (package names and coordinates were refactored) it works like a charm.

Here an example:

```
@Grab('net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3')
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader as opencsv23
@Grab('com.opencsv:opencsv:4.0')
import com.opencsv.CSVReader as opencsv40

new StringReader(
'''GAME_ID,GAME_NAME,OLD_OWNER_NAME,NEW_OWNER_NAME,ORG_NAME
20001,str.git,Gemini,Kitoshi,Blue-DiamondGames
30001,str.git,Kashi,Sensu,FlyingMonkey'''
).withReader { reader ->
    new opencsv23(reader).each { println it }
    println '========================'
    new opencsv40(reader).each { println it }
}
```

Which results in

```
au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader@31e9a763
========================
[GAME_ID, GAME_NAME, OLD_OWNER_NAME, NEW_OWNER_NAME, ORG_NAME]
[20001, str.git, Gemini, Kitoshi, Blue-DiamondGames]
[30001, str.git, Kashi, Sensu, FlyingMonkey]
```